Microsoft MAUI App Debug.WriteLine Not Showing on Android
After working correctly for a long time the output from Debug.WriteLine stopped showing up on Android (it's fine on Windows) using VS2022 Preview (17.13.0 preview 1) but works fine on the released product (17.12.2).
I've got a simple test program built using MAUI and .NET 8 which just writes a few lines in response to a button press, the relevant part looks like this:
private void OnButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 20; i > 0; i--)
        Debug.WriteLine("*************************************************");
}

The whole project is available on GitHub at https://github.com/david-maw/WriteLine.git
Things I've tried so far:

Reboot the development system
Reinstall Visual Studio 2022 Preview
Test on Multiple Android environments
Redirect debug output to immediate window.

Still, Windows always works, Android on VS2022 works, Android on VS2022 Preview has stopped working (I'm pretty sure the same version used to work).
Has anyone got any other ideas?

You’re using a preview build, report it as a bug to the VS team. There’s an option in the Help menu to do this

Thanks @jason, I've done that here, but I'm sufficiently lacking in confidence on matters Android that I thought I'd see if someone had an "oh, silly you, you've set the argle-bargle switch" type of answer. lacking that, I agree, a VS preview bug seems likely and it's certainly possible that this failure came with the preview update.
